# How to detect the traffic of Messages in OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, ip

I want to know the the IP address where my package of Messages data are sent to.

I tried the OS X's Monitor, but it doesn't tell anything about port or IP. And I used `nettop`, there are also no information with name "Messages"

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Little snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) that will give you a graphical Network Monitor where you can select the Messages app and see what are the servers' IP Addresses (IPv4 or IPv6) that Messages app is connected to.

**Note:** You may also need to check imagent and apsd processes.

Nettop will also give you this information, just remember to look for imagent and apsd processes.